# Strange behaviour in Chrome using URI scheme

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, uri, protocols

I'm trying to use custom URI Scheme for one of my application, but in Chrome it seems like only one call can be made per page. I cannot reproduce the error in Firefox.

I made a simple fiddle using mailto: to reproduce the issue. It should fire twice, but Chrome somehow blocking the second one. Is there a way to bypass that somehow?

I tried to create an iframe in the html code and just change the source but I got the same result.

HTML:

```
<div id="appendhere">
  <button id="test">TEST</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    $('<iframe />', {
      name: 'mail',
      id: 'mail'+i,
      width: '1',
      height: '1',
      style: 'visibility:hidden;position:absolute',
      src: 'mailto://'+i,
    }).appendTo('#appendhere');
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4afovga7/

Edit: As I just played around with this fiddle it turned out that if you don't have a default application associated with the emails the above fiddle will fire nothing in Chrome for you.

**Update:** 
As a workaround if I need to append more than one paramter I just wrap the parameters up into a token then from my application I use that token to retrive the parameters.
The number of the parameters basically can be between 0 and 200 so if I append them all at once I probably hit an URL limit. Maybe this is also a better solution than appending hundreds of hidden iframes.
However it is still interesting how Chrome handle the custom URI schemes.

Comment: Both elements appear to be appended to document at jsfiddle ? Is expected result the launch of a desktop email application ?

Comment: As I wrote I use a custom URI scheme like itunes:// or steam:// to pass parameters to a desktop application. The mailto is something similiar and it can reperesent my problem without the requirement to change your registry and install the application.

Comment: Is requirement that two `iframe` elements be appended to `document` ?, or that `iframe` elements launch a specific desktop application ? Tried `window.open()` ? At jsfiddle page appear to reload following appending of iframe to document.

Comment: Not at all. I'm trying to print thermal labels(EPL/ZPL) from a webpage for this I needed a solution that can acces the installed labelprinter on the client machines. The client mark the labels he/she wants to print out then the webpage call that desktop application with a parameter then with this parameter the desktop application make a GET call, get the label code and sends it to the printer. It is possible that 10 or more labels needs to be printed out and it should work "silently" without opening additional pages. Thats the reason I choosed `iframe` as src will fire instantly when appended